# MTO (customized sizing and dynamic pricing)

Tags: magento

I want this functionality, I sell paintings and their sizes are in a certain ratio, so when a customer chooses a width then the lenght must change automatically in ratio, and vice versa, and this should also translate into a price change.

Like in [this](http://www.oceansbridge.com/oil-paintings/product/112019/adeleblochbaueri) site under "Custom Size"

Is there any extension out there for this or a method of how to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Firstly, you only need one **Attribute** because the second one, `height`, is directly linked to the first, `width`. If you want, you can call the Attribute `width_height` and store `X by Y` as the values. ('1 by 2', '2 by 4').

This sounds like a job for **Configurable** products.

You would need to create an attribute called `width`. (Or `width_height`)
Make it suitable for `Configurable` products. (Look this up).

Enter all the possible `width` values into the **Attribute**.
Create the picture as a `configurable` product.
Create the **Simple** product based of the `width`s available.
Use price correction to adjust prices based on the `width`.

Good Luck.

Comment: How exactly do you do this?

Comment: I'd suggest you brush up on your Magento product creation.
If I have some time I may expand the answer. Most of the details have been explained by Magento themselves.
You will need to know how to operate the product creation / Manipluation on Magento at some point anyway.